# Auto-GTP was not able to connect to a simple FTP, it never managed to use the credentials, even though I indicated them

Tags: autogpt

Auto-GTP was not able to connect to a simple FTP, it never managed to use the credentials, even though I indicated them. Has anyone managed to replicate something similar?

read ftp with auto-gtp